# Adding clickable links or onClick handler in a D3 force directed diagram?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When a user clicks on a node in a [D3 force directed diagram](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout), is it possible to send them to a URL or to call JavaScript such as alert("You clicked on node 1")?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes." If you had a more detailed answer in mind, show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A click listener can be applied to a selection. Therefore you can apply it to the nodes by calling an `.on("click",function(d){...})` on your nodes selection. This is not in any kind special for the force layout.

Most of the time force layouts are combined with a drag behavior. You should be aware that the click is also triggered after a drag on the node ends.

If you take [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) of a fore directed diagram, you could use the `node` selection and change it to this:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
    .on("click", function(d){
      console.log(d);
      alert("You clicked on node " + d.name);
    });
    //.call(force.drag);
```

You can leave the `.call(force.drag)` added if you want the click and drag behavior combined.

Comment: Thank you @jhinzmann.  This works great.  A note for others: to keep force.drag, I had to remove the semi-colon right above it.

Comment: I included force.drag.  When I drag and release, it has the same effect as clicking on the node without dragging.  Is there a way to prevent the click behavior from happening if the user drags the node?  I made this a separate question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723592/prevent-click-action-when-dragging-a-d3-node