# Prevent click action when dragging a D3 Node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm able to click on a D3 node to get an `alert()`; message.  I'm able to drag the D3 node too, but dragging also triggers the click behavior when the mouse is released.

Is there a way to prevent the click behavior after dragging the node?

This is where I call drag:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"})
    .on("click", function(d){
        if(d.user_id != "" && d.user_id != null){
            parent.parent.openUserProfile(d.user_id);
        }
    })
    .call(force.drag);
```

One answer below suggests adding something like this code (below), but I think that the code above also has to be modified to make them work together.

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag();
drag.on("dragend", function() {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); // silence other listeners
});
```

Comment: you tried e.preventDefault? (where e, is the event of of click)

Comment: what i did was involve another button press, so i can click and drag but to actually click (select) the node i have to press down shift + left mouse click to do this. Don't know if you want to look in to that, just an idea :)

Comment: with your second question dont pass force.drag to the call function, pass the drag variable to it like so : .call(drag)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior) has mentioned:

> When combining drag behaviors with other event listeners for interaction events, you may also consider stopping propagation on the source event to prevent multiple actions.

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag();
selection.call(drag);

drag.on("dragend", function() {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); // silence other listeners
});
```

Comment: I updated the question above.  Does the first block of code that I posted need to change in order to use "var drag"?

Comment: I do not have much idea about `d3` API but i believe you can now use `call(drag)` instead of `call(force.drag)`. `dragend` handler is attached to drag so it can be placed independently in the scope of `drag`. Does it makes sense?

Comment: I marked this as the accepted answer.  Thank you.  I should have mentioned in my question that my use case was the force-directed graph.  It turns out that it has an additional option which is listed at the bottom of https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout which is this: selection.on("click", function(d) { if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; otherwiseDoAwesomeThing(); });